# nl2br or str_replace not working for $_GET variable

Tags: php, get, str-replace, nl2br

I have searched and searched but it seems i'm the only one having this problem. So I want to convert line breaks from this $_GET variable.
So this is my url:

```
test.php?name=Line%201\nLine%202\rLine%203\r\nLine%204
```

In my code I have tried:

```
print nl2br($_GET['name']); //doesn't work
```

I have also tried:

```
print str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $name); //doesn't work
```

Every time it prints out the original string (Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n) with no change.
However if I try it with a variable that is not passed in it always works. For instance:

```
$other = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
print `nl2br($_GET['name']);
print str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $other);
```

I have also tried doing this in a tottaly new document, where I don't have any "sanitizing" scripts or any other scripts still can't get around it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because the characters sent are literally '\n' not a newline.

The GET request should probably be something like `First+line%0ASecond+line`;

If you can't change the request you can change the replace to escape the slashes:

```
print str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\r", "\\n"), "<br>", $name);
```

Comment: thanks, indeed it was the slashes, didn't come to me

Answer (score 3):

You have to decode this var first using `urldecode()`. It'll change url entities to actual chars.

Try replacing as normal strings `str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\r", "\\n"), "<br>", $name);`
It'll replace literal eg `\n`, not `new line`.

Comment: I have tried that already, doesn't work, also from the php site i see that they say "The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results."

Comment: @justsomeguy show `var_dump` of `$_GET` but copied from `view source`.

Comment: @justsomeguy And value, I think :)

Comment: yeah, sorry, from view source: string(32) "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4"

Comment: @justsomeguy So they're normal chars not new lines. Will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urldecode()` function which returns the decoded URL as a string.:

```
<?php

echo urldecode('Line%201\nLine%202\rLine%203\r\nLine%204'); 

?>
```